# grep and extract from .log file and paste as shell command in shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have a list of files in a directory with extension `.gz` and for that same list I need to `grep` from `final.log` and get the same file `name.gz.DONE` name by using `grep` and need to search for the entire list of files from the directory, so that I can prepare a `touch -d` command from using `.gz.DONE`.

Example:

```
VIC_sentine_1153690_20220503_153250_0000.psv.gz
VIC_sentine_1151176_20220504_153250_0000.psv.gz
VIC_sentine_175390_20220505_153250_0000.psv.gz
```

from the `.log` file.

When I do `grep` below like this

```
a=VIC_sentine_1153690_20220503_153250_0000.psv.gz

cat ~/final.log | grep $a | grep DONE | cut -d '/'  -f 7 | head -n 1
```

I get  `VIC_sentine_1153690_20220503_153250_0000.psv.gz.20220523081154.DONE`

by using `.DONE` file, the timestamp from the same `.gz` in the directory I'm generating manually

```
touch -d "2022-05-03 21:04:00.000000000" VIC_sentine_1153690_20220503_153250_0000.psv.gz.20220523081154.DONE
```

but there are 200 files in the directory.

Is there a way to cross check the `.gz` file with the same `.gz.*DONE` (as there are some numeric involved between `.gz` & `.DONE`) exists?

If not then generate a `touch` command and output that command to some `.txt` file. All I need is to generate `touch` commands dynamically from that directory by grepping to the log file.

Comment: It looks like this is some kind of job queue - is that correct?  I don't have an answer for you at this stage, just a few comments/suggestions.  1. It's generally better to move completed job files to a different directory (or just delete them if you don't need them) - i.e. instead of touching a `.DONE` file, just mv the file to a `done/` directory.  2. `cat | grep | grep | cut | head` is just awful.  try `awk -F/ -v a="$a" '$0 ~ a && /DONE/ {print $7; last}' ~/final.log` instead. 3. Depending on what your job queue process does, it's probably better to use awk, perl, or python than shell.

Comment: Also, GNU touch has a `-r` (`--reference`) option that you can use to touch a file to have the same timestamp as another file, so you don't need to generate a timestamp for `-d` manually.